# Just started Javascript (by that I mean I just typed the word javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, var

Here's a code i tried to study by changing stuff in it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- hide this script from old browsers
function temp(form)
{
  var f = parseFloat(form.DegF.value, 10);
  var c = 0;
  c = (f - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
  form.DegC.value = c;
}
// done hiding from old browsers -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<FORM>
<h2>Fahrenheit to Celsius Converter</h2>
Enter a temperature in degrees F: 
<INPUT NAME="DegF" VALUE="0" MAXLENGTH="15" SIZE=15>
<p>
Click this button to calculate the temperature 
in degrees C:
<INPUT NAME="calc" VALUE="Calculate" TYPE=BUTTON 
onClick=temp(this.form)>
<p>
Temperature in degrees C is: 
<INPUT NAME="DegC" READONLY SIZE=15>
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

But I cannot figure out why the guy who wrote this code included 10 in the variable f line
var f = parseFloat(form.DegF.value, 10);
Why is the value 10 there?
The ouput did'nt change when it removed it.

Comment: The author did it because he or she was confused. The `parseFloat()` function only pays attention to the first parameter.

Comment: `parseFloat` only takes one parameter, so it is indeed useless.

Comment: [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) accepts an optional parameter which is the radix of the number. If you don't supply it, it would guess. Nowadays, it is pretty OK to miss it out but old IE versions were rather bad at assuming what the base of the number was. Presumably whoever wrote the code didn't realise this is [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) which doesn't accept a radix parameter.

Comment: Also that "hide script" stuff hasn't been necessary for almost 20 years. If you're learning, you'd do yourself a big favor by finding a solid recent textbook.

Comment: Wow That was quick. Thanks

Comment: @Pointy, Will do that, thanks